# cellTemplate and rowTemplate resources not loaded from browser cache

Tags: angular-ui-grid

If we use a cellTemplate or rowTemplate that points to an html file, apparently angular tries to fetch it from the server each time it is needed. This happens even if the cache-control header maxAge is set to a distant date.
Ideally, they should be pulled from the browser cache. Is there any way to enable this?

Regards,

Yash

Comment: Are you using $templateCache https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you look at the ui-grid code, it has to use $http to load an html fragment, **and** it *is loaded* into $templateCache **but** because it's done on a promise resolve, if you try to load it a lot of times fast, it doesn't know about the previous try!

Comment: Even after some time if I navigate to a link which shows the same grid, I see calls being made to the server to fetch the template. So it looks like templateCache is not used. Also the browser cache is not used.

Comment: My experience indicates that if I have 4 grids on a page, as it is rendered, the template is queued via http 4 times. After that, it is taken from cache. Is it possible you have an error in the template so it is rejected in some manner? You could start by inserting the template as a string in your gridOptions...